# Default style for nested unordered and ordered lists

Tags: css

According to [CSS Default Values Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp), both the `ol` and `ul` elements have their top and bottom margins set to `1em`.

But if this were the case, then nested lists would add a vertical margin with any new level, like this:

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li>Consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```

Yet, every browser that I have tested present nested lists without any extra vertical margins, like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li>Consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
      <li>Consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```

My question is: What is the (real) default style for `ol` and `ul` elements, specially for the one that are nested.

Comment: there is an extra rule that disable the margin for `ul ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default style for single `ul`/`ol` is `1em` `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`,

For nested lists (`ul ul`,`ul ol`,`ol ul`, `ol ol`) it is `0` `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`.

You may also notice how the default `list-style-type` changes from `disc` to `circle` to `square`.

You can always check with developer tools, or look up the user agent sheet of the browser, here are [Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css), [Firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css) and [Safari](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)